# Material Design Lite Icons missing when using in Angular

Tags: css, angularjs, material-design

So I started to use [MDL](https://getmdl.io/) inside my Angular project, which works mostly fine, but the MDL icons are just not working in there...

I'm using them like this `<i class="material-icons">share</i>` and the browser just writes "share" as normal font and not as Icon like it should do it. I've got the mdl css and js included and also got the angular-material-design-lite package included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I just had to install the font via bower : `bower install material-design-icons --save` and add this to my css :

```
.material-icons {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap: normal;
    direction: ltr;
    -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure all fonts assets(.woff,.svg,.tff etc) are correctly installed, also the font-face in your css sheet is referred in the correct path.